Multiple input elements are getting focused
I have two OutlinedInput in the UI, when i click on any of them, both are getting focused. I tried using normal HTML input tag to check, normal input elements are working fine. I have attached the UI screenshot and the code. First snippet is of my component file and second one is of CSS file.
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import '../App.css'
import FormHelperText from '@mui/material/FormHelperText';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import  FormControl  from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import { Input } from '@mui/material';

const LeftComponent = ({splitterObj,setSplitterObj}) => {

    const handleBillChange = (e)=>{
        console.log(splitterObj);
        setSplitterObj({...splitterObj, bill: e.target.value})
    }
    const handleTipChange = (e)=>{
        setSplitterObj({...splitterObj, customTip:e.target.value})
    }
    const handlePersonChange = (e)=>{
        setSplitterObj({...splitterObj, noOfPeople: e.target.value,errorNoOfPeople:false})
    }

    return (
        <>
    <Grid container direction={'column'} sx={{'padding-right':'10px'}} spacing={2.5}>
        <Grid item>
        <label for="bill">Bill</label><br></br>

        <OutlinedInput
            className='text-input'
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="17"><path fill="#9EBBBD" d="M6.016 16.328v-1.464c1.232-.08 2.22-.444 2.964-1.092.744-.648 1.116-1.508 1.116-2.58v-.144c0-.992-.348-1.772-1.044-2.34-.696-.568-1.708-.932-3.036-1.092V4.184c.56.144 1.012.4 1.356.768.344.368.516.816.516 1.344v.288h1.824v-.432c0-.448-.088-.876-.264-1.284a3.783 3.783 0 00-.744-1.116A4.251 4.251 0 007.54 2.9a5.324 5.324 0 00-1.524-.492V.872H4.288V2.36a5.532 5.532 0 00-1.416.324c-.448.168-.84.392-1.176.672-.336.28-.604.616-.804 1.008-.2.392-.3.844-.3 1.356v.144c0 .96.316 1.708.948 2.244.632.536 1.548.884 2.748 1.044v3.912c-.704-.16-1.248-.472-1.632-.936-.384-.464-.576-1.08-.576-1.848v-.288H.256v.576c0 .464.08.924.24 1.38.16.456.404.88.732 1.272.328.392.744.728 1.248 1.008s1.108.476 1.812.588v1.512h1.728zM4.288 7.424c-.688-.128-1.164-.332-1.428-.612-.264-.28-.396-.644-.396-1.092 0-.464.176-.832.528-1.104.352-.272.784-.448 1.296-.528v3.336zm1.728 5.712V9.344c.768.128 1.328.328 1.68.6.352.272.528.688.528 1.248 0 .544-.196.984-.588 1.32-.392.336-.932.544-1.62.624z"/></svg></InputAdornment>}
            inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'right' } }}
            sx={{
                'fontFamily':'Space Mono',
                'font-size': '1.3rem',
                'font-weight': 'bold',
                'color': 'hsl(183, 100%, 15%)',
                'text-align':'right !important'
            }}
            placeholder='0'
            value={splitterObj.bill}
            onChange={handleBillChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
        <label for="bill">Select Tip %</label><br></br><br></br>
        <Grid container direction={'row'} spacing={3} alignItems={'stretch'}>
            <Grid item xs={4}><Button value='5' onClick={handleTipChange} className='tip-button' variant="contained">5%</Button></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}><Button value='10' onClick={handleTipChange} className='tip-button' variant="contained">10%</Button></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}><Button value='15' onClick={handleTipChange} className='tip-button' variant="contained">15%</Button></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}><Button value='25' onClick={handleTipChange} className='tip-button' variant="contained">25%</Button></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}><Button value='50' onClick={handleTipChange} className='tip-button' variant="contained">50%</Button></Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}><TextField value={splitterObj.customTip} onChange={handleTipChange} id="outlined-basic" placeholder='Custom' variant="outlined" inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'right' } }} /></Grid>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
        <Grid container direction={'row'} justifyContent={'space-between'} sx={{'margin-bottom':'10px'}}>
        <Grid item xs={6}><label for="bill">Number of People</label></Grid>
        {splitterObj.errorNoOfPeople&&(<Grid item xs={6}><FormHelperText sx={{'textAlign':'right','margin-right':'0','font-family':'Space Mono'}} error>Can't be zero</FormHelperText></Grid>)}
        </Grid>
        <OutlinedInput
            className='text-input'
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="16"><path fill="#9EBBBD" d="M9.573 7.729c.406 0 .784.07 1.126.209.342.14.639.33.881.569.232.227.438.503.614.82a5.1 5.1 0 01.407.949c.097.312.178.654.242 1.016.062.359.105.699.126 1.011.02.307.031.624.031.945 0 .836-.259 1.512-.768 2.01-.504.492-1.17.742-1.98.742H2.748c-.81 0-1.477-.25-1.98-.742C.259 14.76 0 14.084 0 13.248c0-.322.01-.64.032-.945.02-.312.063-.652.126-1.01.063-.363.144-.705.242-1.017.1-.323.238-.643.407-.948.176-.318.382-.594.613-.821.243-.238.54-.43.882-.57.342-.138.72-.208 1.125-.208.16 0 .313.067.61.265.183.123.397.264.636.421.204.134.48.259.822.372.333.11.671.167 1.005.167a3.19 3.19 0 001.006-.167c.341-.113.618-.238.822-.372l.636-.42c.296-.2.45-.266.61-.266zM6.598 0C7.63 0 8.522.38 9.252 1.129s1.1 1.666 1.1 2.724c0 1.06-.37 1.976-1.1 2.725-.73.75-1.623 1.13-2.654 1.13-1.03 0-1.924-.38-2.653-1.13-.73-.749-1.1-1.666-1.1-2.725 0-1.058.37-1.975 1.1-2.724C4.675.379 5.567 0 6.598 0z"/></svg></InputAdornment>}
            inputProps={{
                style: { textAlign: 'right' }
            }}
          error={splitterObj.errorNoOfPeople}
            sx={{
                'fontFamily':'Space Mono',
                'font-size': '1.3rem',
                'font-weight': 'bold',
                'color': 'hsl(183, 100%, 15%)'
            }}
            value={splitterObj.noOfPeople}
            onChange={handlePersonChange}
            placeholder='0'
          />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>   
    </>
    );
}

export default LeftComponent;

`


*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Space Mono';
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
}
body{
  background-color: #c5e4e7;
}
.text-top{
  min-width: 450px;
  margin-top: 3vh ;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.content{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 32px;
  /* width: 70vw !important; */
  min-width: 450px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin: 5vh auto !important;
}
.text-input{
  text-align: right;
  width: 100% !important;
  
}
.tip-custom{
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100%; 
  border: none;
  background-color: #2bc1af !important;
}
.tip-button{
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Space Mono' !important;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%) !important;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;;
  
}
.tip-button:hover{
  background-color: #2bc1af !important;
  color:hsl(183, 100%, 15%)
} 


/* Right content */

.right-content{
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 4vh 3vw;
}
.reset-button{
  width: 100% !important;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #2bbba6 !important;
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%) !important;
  font-size: 1rem !important;
}



`
I am trying to implement a simple UI. Both inputs are getting focused, i just want only clicked one to get focused
UI Screenshot

I can see that you have for="bill" attributes used 3 times without an id="bill" set for your input. Not sure why the focus is happening in the first place. Can't run the code and the screenshot isn't helping, can you share a sandbox?
